# Java: Preserving dot after word stemming using Wordnet and JWNL

Tags: java, wordnet

I am using JWNL to check a word and return the stem for the word (exp: knew -> know). It is working fine but how do I preserve the period (dot) included in a word (exp: knew. -> know.) because it removes the period everytime a stem a word with a dot.

```
String x = stem.StemWordWithWordNet ("knew.");
System.out.println(x);
```

The code for the word stemming is here: http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Other/JavaStemmer.html
Or is there a way I could include a period into a stemmed word if it detected a period? 
Anyone familiar with this? Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with JWNL, but why don't you just reappend the `.`, if it was present in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word stemmer works on words only, so to include things like periods & full-stops you need to do that externally.

An easy way to do this is to define your own stemming method that support these details, it pays off when it's reused all over your project.

```
String stemWord(Stemmer s, String word) throws Exception
{
    return s.StemWordWithWordNet(word)
    + (word.charAt(word.length()-1)=='.'?".":"");
}
```

then use it like this

```
String x = stemWord(stem,"knew.");
System.out.println(x);

String x = stemWord(stem,"knew");
System.out.println(x);
```